# How insert into morph related model in eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Using the laravel ducmunet example :

There are there table like

```
posts
    id - integer
    title - string
    body - text

videos
    id - integer
    title - string
    url - string

comments
    id - integer
    body - text
    commentable_id - integer
    commentable_type - string

And 3 model (post, command and video) .
Comment model has morphTo relation with post and video.

<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comment extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the owning commentable models.
     */
    public function commentable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

class Post extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the post's comments.
     */
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Comment', 'commentable');
    }
}

class Video extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the video's comments.
     */
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Comment', 'commentable');
    }
}
```

Is there a solution for insert new record into model related  to the comment (video or post model).

For example if i have an instace of comment model by this instrument :

```
$nc = comment::find(3);
```

Now how can i add new post or video related to $nc comment.

I can't use save method because save method argument is an instance of post or video model but i don't know which model related to $nc comment by polymorphic.
in another word i will add a new post or video to a comment existing ($nc).

Comment: so, to confirm things, you want to relate a video or post  to a comment?

Comment: @bagus-tesa Yes . new video or post record created in posts or videos table belongs to $nc Comment. in another word i will add new post or video to a comment existing ($nc)

Comment: i think there is a slight miscommunication, i thought it was one video/post have many comment (should already answered in my answer). but your answers looks like a single comment can have several video/post. if it's true, your relation a bit mismatch.. wait a bit.

Answer (score 5):

You could always use [`associate()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/MorphTo.php#L117) and [`dissociate()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/MorphTo.php#L131) just like [`BelongsTo`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships) relation. For example:

```
$video = Video::find(1);
$comment = new Comment();
$comment->commentable()->associate($video);
$comment->save()
```

Just a reminder, one comment **belongs to** a single video or post. Happy coding!

Comment: Doesn't work. This raises BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method App/Models/MyModel::associate()'

Comment: wah my bad, i havent code laravel for a while. the `associate` method should be on the relation (on this case commentable). you are right. thank you for the help good sir.

Answer (score 5):

Improving Bagus answer with the Correct way to use associate()

```
$video = Video::find(1)

$comment = new Comment();
$comment->commentable()->associate($video);
$comment->save();
```